# CSS to Replace Table Layout for Forms

Tags: css, forms, css-tables

I've looked at other questions and am unable to find the solution to this.  Consider this image: [mockup http://img201.imageshack.us/img201/935/image2h.png](http://img201.imageshack.us/img201/935/image2h.png)

I want to wrap divs and stack them vertically.  The GREEN div would be a wrapper on a line.  The BLUE div would contain an html label and maybe icon for a tooltip.  The ORANGE div would contain some sort of entry (input, select, textarea).

Several of these would be stacked vertically to make up a form.  I am doing this now, but I have to specify a height for the container div and that really needs to change depending on the content - considering any entry could land there.  Images and other stuff could land here, as well.

I have a width set on the BLUE div and the ORANGE is float:left.  How can I get rid of the height on divs and let that be determined by content?  Is there a better way?  Changing all to something else would be difficult and would prefer a way to style all elements or something.

The code I'm using is like:

```
<div class=EntLine>
    <div class=EntLbl>
      <label for="Name">Name</label>
    </div>
    <div class=EntFld>
      <input type=text id="Name" />
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS looks like:

```
.EntLine {
  height: 20px;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 2px;
  text-align: left;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.EntLbl {
  float: left;
  width: 120px;
  padding: 3px 0px 0px 3px;
  min-width: 120px;
  max-width: 120px;
  vertical-align: text-top;
}

.EntFld {
  float: left;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Although not an exact answer to your particular question, there's an extensive discussion of styling forms in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2174633/form-layout-using-css

Answer (score 1):

Well, for a start I think you could use less mark-up to achieve your aim. You might have a good reason for wrapping a `div` around every element of your form, but if it's just to force a single label-input pair to each line then you can nest the `input` inside the `label` tag:

```
      <label for="Name">Name
          <input type="text" id="Name" />
      </label>
```

This way you can use a simple:

```
label {display: block; }
```

to force each pair to their own line. This would also remove the need to `float` the `label`s, which removes the need to specify the `height` of any containing element.

You can still apply multiple classes to the relevant fields/labels, but it's far less trouble. Unless I'm really missing something.

Failing all of that, you could simply add an empty `div` (or other element), after the last of your fields and style with:

```
#empty_element {
disply: block;
height: 0;
clear: both; /* to force the parent element to expand to contain this element and, by extension, any non 'position:absolute' siblings that precede it in the mark-up */
visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: One reason for doing that is to ensure consistency in the app regardless of the form the user is seeing.  It's also easier for me to read and much easier to maintain consistency for other developers I have working for me.  I can give them the chunk of code above and allow no variations.  The extra markup is not so much a problem as it is a solution in this case.

Comment: You find it easier to work with five nested elements -instead of two- for every label/input pair? I'm surprised, but it's your shop...see the edit, for a possible solution that'll force the containing-element to expand to include the children, though it *does* involve adding yet another element to the form(s).